# UITextView highlightedTextColor or similar option?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UILabel` and a `UITextView` in it.

I want the text for both of these to appear white when the user highlights the `UITableViewCell`. It's obviously very simple to set the `highlightedTextColor` of the `UILabel`, but the `UITextView` doesn't seem to have any similar type of property. Am I going to have to manually change the color of the `UITextView` whenever the cell becomes highlighted/unhighlighted or is there an easier way of accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it and it was a lot easier than I thought. Just need to use the `UITableViewCell` `setHighlighted` method.

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];

    if (highlighted) {
        [self.myTextView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    } else {
        [self.myTextView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; 
    }

}
```

Comment: To prevent non-selectable rows from changing text color, modify to: if (highlighted && (self.selectionStyle != UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone))

Comment: This is worked only for first and last row can you tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

The solution posted by the author is half right for my situation.  Need to keep in mind that the following events happen:

1. press down --> setHighlighted:YES animated: is called
2. press up --> setHighlighted:NO animated is called
3. set selection --> setSelected:YES animated is called

Knowing this, and depending on how you want the TableCell to look when highighted vs when selected will determine if you need to implement setHighlighted:animated:, setSelected:animated: or both methods.

For the look I want, I need to implement both methods.